# DOMDocument cannot parse curl response

Tags: php, web-scraping, domdocument, php-curl

I'm having trouble with this. I'm trying to get all the div tag but it's not returning any, this is the exact code and domain

```
<?php
$url = 'jwdpit.com';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($response);
$table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
print_r($table);
```

this is the output of print

> DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to return the value of `curl_exec` instead of outputting it directly:

```
<?php
$url = 'jwdpit.com';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //added curl option
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($response);
$table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
print_r($table); //DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 16 )
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php